# What is the purpose of the 'WaitReason' parameter on KeWaitForSingleObject()?

Tags: windows, driver, drivers, wdk

[The MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553350.aspx) don't explain what happens for the various options here (despite being quite clear about the 'WaitMode' paramter). Why would I pick 'Executive' over 'UserRequest' or the myriad other options in KWAIT_REASON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that this value is set into the invoking thread's _KTHREAD::WaitReason field, and that it there strictly for diagnostic purposes.

_KTHREAD::WaitReasonis consumed and displayed by various Windows diagnostic services.

Comment: Aha! That corroborates what I found [here](http://www.winvistatips.com/meaning-enum-kwait_reason-t181544.html)